# Debian LiveBuild: How to make the bootloader to directly boot to live?

Tags: debian, live-build

I just start learning on using LiveBuild.
I want it to boot directly in 'Live' mode, no other boot choice(s)

Here is my auto/config

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

lb config noauto \
    --mode debian \
    --distribution buster \
    --architectures i386 \
    --linux-flavours 686-pae \
    --debian-installer false \
        --apt-recommends false \
        --debootstrap-options "--variant=minbase" \
        --firmware-chroot false \
    --apt-indices false \
        --bootloaders syslinux \
    --memtest none \
"${@}"
```

here is my config/bootloaders/syslinux/syslinux.cfg

```
include menu.cfg
#default vesamenu.c32
default live-@FLAVOUR@
prompt 0
timeout 1
```

And here is config/bootloaders/syslinux/menu.cfg

```
menu hshift 0
menu width 82

menu title Boot menu
#include stdmenu.cfg
timeout 1
label live-@FLAVOUR@
    menu label ^Live (@FLAVOUR@)
    menu default
    linux @LINUX@
    initrd @INITRD@
    append @APPEND_LIVE@
```

But still when booted, it always show the standard boot menu and do nothing until I press ENTER.

[image: Stdandard Boot Menu]

Kindly please give me some clue to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you still haven't found your answer, I'm guessing that the bootloader on your live media isn't actually `syslinux`.

You can check it by simply opening your live media and looking at the folders in it: often it isn't `syslinux` but `isolinux`. In this case you need to have a template for it in the folder `config/bootloaders` (you can get one in `/usr/share/live/build/bootloaders`).

For the timeout setting, the `*.cfg` in `isolinux` is similar to the `syslinux` one.

Answer (score 0):

You are booting in `isolinux` because you boot in BIOS mode.